# How do I sort an NSMutableArray with class objects in it?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a class `Events`

```
@interface MeEvents : NSObject {
    NSString* name;**strong text**
    NSString* location;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* name;strong text
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* location;
```

In my NSMutablArray I add object of Events

```
Events* meEvent;
[tempArray addObject:meEvent];
```

Please tell me how to sort this array by member name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `sortUsingComparator:` like this:

```
[tempArray sortUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    return [[a name] compare:[b name]];
}];
```

If you are sorting these strings because you want to show a sorted list to the user, you should `localizedCompare:` instead:

```
[tempArray sortUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    return [[a name] localizedCompare:[b name]];
}];
```

Or you might want to use `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDes = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
        [tempArray_ sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDes]];
        [sortDes release];
```

Comment: This give SIGABRT error.Sir my array return class object like <Events 0xab00240> Then i receive object in Events* meEvent=[temparray objectAtIndex:i];  NSLog(@"Name   %@",meEvent.eventname);

Comment: @SawanCool: You have to define the key in ["initWithKey:""].In the above code i just give an example as "name".Please init the sortDescriptor with your key.

Answer (score 2):

Declare this at the top of the implementation file above @interface line

```
NSComparisonResult sortByName(id firstItem, id secondItem, void *context);
```

Following is the implementation for the method

```
NSComparisonResult sortByName(id item1, id item2, void *context)
{
    NSString *strItem1Name = [item1 name];
    NSString *strItem2Name = [item2 name];

    return [strItem1Name compare:strItem2Name]; //Ascending for strItem1Name you can reverse comparison for having descending result
}
```

This is how you would call it

```
[tempArray sortUsingFunction:sortByName context:@"Names"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array using [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)'s

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator
```

method

For more detail, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it) SO answer